# jsf unable to hide the div

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I am new to JSF. Any help would be appreciated. :)

.xhtml file

```
    <ui:composition template="templates/layoutTemplate.xhtml"  
     xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

        <ui:define name="script"> <h:outputScript library="javascript"  name="resources/datetimepicker-master/jquery.datetimepicker.js"  target="head"/>  </ui:define>
         <ui:define name="content">
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-left:25px;">
                      <div class="well bs-component">
                      <legend>New Patient</legend>
                      <h:form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="inputPatientNumber" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Patient
                                        Id </label>

                                            <div class='col-sm-4' >
                                                <h:inputText id="inputPatientNumber" styleClass="form-control" 
                                                    p:placeholder="patient Id" value="#{addPatient.patientId}"   >

                                                    <f:ajax event="blur" listener="#{addPatient.isExitsPatientId}" render="hiddenText" >

                                                    </f:ajax>
                                                     <f:ajax update="addPatientForm" />
                                                </h:inputText> 

                                            </div>
                                             <br/>
                                            <h:inputHidden id="hiddenText" value="#{addPatient.isNewPatient}"   ></h:inputHidden> 

                                    </div>
                      </h:form>
                      <br/>
                      <h:panelGroup  id="addPatientForm" layout="block"  style="display:#{addPatient.isNewPatient}" rendered="#{addPatient.newPatient  }">
                         <div>   
                            <h:form class="form-horizontal"   >


                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="patientFirstName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">First Name</label>
                                        <div class='col-sm-4'>
                                                <h:inputText id="patientFirstName" styleClass="form-control" 
                                                    p:placeholder="First Name" value="#{addPatient.firstName}" required="true"  requiredMessage="First name required" validatorMessage="allowed alphabets only">
                                                     <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"/>
                                                </h:inputText> 
                                                 <h:message for="patientFirstName" style="color:red;margin:8px;" /> 
                                        </div>
                                        <label for="patientLastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
                                        <div class='col-sm-3'>
                                                <h:inputText id="patientLastName" styleClass="form-control" 
                                                    p:placeholder="Last Name" value="#{addPatient.lastName}" required="true" requiredMessage="Last name required"   validatorMessage="allowed alphabets only">
                                                    <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"/>
                                                </h:inputText> 
                                                  <h:message for="patientLastName" style="color:red;margin:8px;" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="dateOfBirth" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date Of Birth </label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class='input-group date'>
                                                <h:inputText id="dateOfBirth"  styleClass="form-control" value="#{addPatient.dob}" p:placeholder="13-12-1985" required="true" requiredMessage="Provide a valid date">
                                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />

                                                </h:inputText>

                                                 <h:message for="dateOfBirth" style="color:red;margin:8px;" />

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <label for="gender" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gender </label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                              <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="genderType" value="#{addPatient.gender}" required="true" requiredMessage="select gender">
                                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--Gender --" />
                                                    <f:selectItem  itemValue="Male"  itemLabel="Male"/>
                                                    <f:selectItem   itemValue="Female" itemLabel="Female" /> 
                                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                                                 <h:message for="genderType" style="color:red;margin:8px;" />
                                        </div>


                                    </div>


                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Identification Type </label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">


                                                <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="identificationType" value="#{addPatient.identificationType}" required="true" requiredMessage="Select the identification type">
                                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--Select ID Type --" />
                                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Passport Number" />
                                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Driving Licence" />
                                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Social Security Code" />
                                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Permanent Account Number" />

                                                </h:selectOneMenu>

                                              <h:message for="identificationType" style="color:red;margin:8px;" />
                                        </div>
                                        <label for="idType" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ID </label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">

                                            <h:inputText id="idType" value="#{addPatient.identificationNumber}" styleClass="form-control" p:placeholder="id" required="true" requiredMessage="Provide your id">

                                            </h:inputText> 
                                             <h:message for="idType" style="color:red;margin:8px;" />
                                        </div> 
                                    </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="address" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                                        <h:inputText id="address" value="#{addPatient.address}" styleClass="form-control" p:placeholder="address"  required="true"  requiredMessage="Provide your address">

                                        </h:inputText>
                                         <h:message for="address" style="color:red;margin:8px;" />
                                    </div>  
                                    <label for="line1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Line 1 </label>
                                    <div class='col-sm-3'>
                                        <h:inputText id="line1" value="#{addPatient.addressLine1}" styleClass="form-control" p:placeholder="line 1"  >
                                        </h:inputText>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="line2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Line 2 </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                                        <h:inputText id="line2" value="#{addPatient.addressLine2}" styleClass="form-control" p:placeholder="line 2"  >

                                        </h:inputText>
                                    </div>  
                                    <label for="city" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City </label>
                                    <div class='col-sm-3'>
                                        <h:inputText id="city" value="#{addPatient.addressCity}" styleClass="form-control" p:placeholder="city"  >
                                        </h:inputText>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="state" class="col-sm-3 control-label">State </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                                        <h:inputText id="state" value="#{addPatient.addressState}" styleClass="form-control" p:placeholder="state"  >

                                        </h:inputText>
                                    </div>  
                                    <label for="postalCode" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Postal Code </label>
                                    <div class='col-sm-2'>
                                        <h:inputText id="postalCode" value="#{addPatient.addressPostalCode}" styleClass="form-control" p:placeholder="Postal Code"  >
                                        </h:inputText>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="mobile" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Mobile </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                                        <h:inputText id="mobile" value="#{addPatient.patientMobileNumber}"  size="20" styleClass="form-control" p:placeholder="Mobile Number" required="true" requiredMessage="Mobile Number is required" validatorMessage="mobile number should start with + and can not be more than 15 digits.">
                                            <f:validateRegex pattern="((^[/+][0-9]{0,12}$))" />
                                             <f:validateLength minimum="12" maximum="15" />

                                        </h:inputText>
                                         <h:message for="mobile" style="color:red;margin:8px;" />
                                    </div>  
                                    <label for="line1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Language </label>
                                    <div class='col-sm-3'>
                                        <h:inputText id="language" value="#{addPatient.language}" styleClass="form-control" p:placeholder="language" >
                                        </h:inputText>

                                    </div>

                                </div>





                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3   ">
                                        <h:commandButton class="btn btn-default" value="Clear" type="reset" />
                                        <h:outputText value="&#160;" />

                                    </div>
                                     <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-5  "> 
                                        <h:commandButton action="#{addPatient.nextClick}"   value="Next" styleClass="btn btn-primary"/> 


                                    </div>  
                                </div>

                            </div>



                            </h:form>
                                </div>
                      </h:panelGroup>

                        </div>
                </div>



         </ui:define>

     </ui:composition>
```

BEAN

```
 public String isExitsPatientId(AjaxBehaviorEvent e){

   ExternalContext externalContext =        
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    String orgId = (String)externalContext.getSessionMap().get(JansmsDrapSolutionSqlQueryConstants.ALS_ORGID);
    System.out.println(patientId +"org ="+ orgId);

    sLogger.debug("Patient info being retrieved...");
    ResultSet rSet;
    String retrievePatientInfo = queryFile.getProperty(JansmsDrapSolutionSqlQueryConstants.SQL_QUERY_PATIENT_EXITS);
    retrievePatientInfo = retrievePatientInfo.replaceAll("ALS_PATIENT_EXT_ID", patientId);
    retrievePatientInfo = retrievePatientInfo.replaceAll("ORGID", orgId);
    sLogger.debug(retrievePatientInfo);
    try {
        rSet = dbInteraction.executeQuery(retrievePatientInfo);
        //patientMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

        Integer counter = 0;
        while(rSet.next()) {
            counter++;
        }
        if(counter>0){

            this.isNewPatient =  "none";
            newPatient = false;
            sLogger.debug("patient already exits" + newPatient);
            return this.isNewPatient;

        }else{
            this.isNewPatient = "true"; 
            newPatient = true;
            sLogger.debug("new patient" + newPatient);


        }


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return "addPatient";
}
```

The isExitsPatientId() method is providing correct boolean value and either true or none for isNewPatient bean. However, the ui is not hidden until i press enter twice. by removing the focus on inputText calls the isExitsPatientId() method and provides the correct data but hiding the panelGroup is not working.

Comment: Use only `rendered=#{boolean condition}` attribute to show/hide. don't use `style="display:#{..}"`

Comment: Please try to show only the piece of code which you think it is erroneous.

Comment: @Ali Helmy  i have the boolean condition <h:panelGroup style="display:#{addPatient.isNewPatient}" layout="block"    rendered="#{addPatient.newPatient == true}"> Tiny this is piece of section i think is not working :(

Comment: First remove style part and change == to eq keyword in jstl

Comment: @AliHelmy,i have tried everything of that with no luck

Comment: Can you put this id="addPatientForm"" in h:panelGroup instead of form

Comment: @AliHelmy no help :(

Comment: Can you update the question with your last code, please

Comment: @AliHelmy i have updated the question. Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: can you remove this part `style="display:#{addPatient.isNewPatient}"`

Comment: @AliHelmy no luck :(

Comment: I changed the code, could you try now, i changed the id and assigned id to the form

Comment: @AliHelmy: JSTL? To learn what exactly JSTL is, carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info And, please don't edit comments or answers into a question. Post comments as comments and answers as answers.

Comment: @BalusC thanks alot for sharing. Actually i know what is EL and JSTL. But i meant by JSTL  the full tag. And i didnt write an answer because i am not sure it will help or not. Thanks for try helping in answering the question

Comment: @AliHelmy: still, read that link. There's nothing of JSTL anywhere in the question.

Comment: :( nothing happening as i have to enter twice to get the div hidden or shown.